# After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10 I see issues when resizing windows or dragging windows

Tags: video, 19.10

Link to youtube video that shows the issue.  The video does not have any sound.  I cannot confirm my microphone stopped working after the upgrade because my mic. has flailed out previously.

Anyone else encountering this issue.  Currently running in KVM 2.1.0 8 GB allocated RAM, with 4 CPUs allocated.

https://youtu.be/d95VlVFUUCM

This ilustrates the problem:
[image: Problem dragging file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a similar issue and fixed it by removing an extension that was causing issues:

```
~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
rm -rf desktop-icons@csoriano/
```

The log out, log back in and everything is good.

Your problem might not be exactly the same but I think it is worth try disabling/removing any gnome shell extensions you might have.