# 19.10: Stuttered echos of windows in background when moving

Tags: gnome, graphics, 19.10

This started with my upgrade to 19.10 a few months ago. I'm guessing it's something with how the background gets drawn. If I set a background manually the problem goes away temporarily but typically comes back. The effect once it's drawn reminds me of the solitaire win animation.

It's mostly a nuisance since the artifacts make it hard to tell which windows are real. Covering the background with a fullscreen window works too.

A fix would be nice but i'm more curious about why/how this is happening since it seems like an interesting problem. How does the background work?

[image: artifacts]

Another interesting effect from closing a window. 
[image]

Comment: It's probably your video driver. Do you have Nvidia?

Comment: It's on a laptop with amd graphics. But I do occasionally use an external Nvidia gpu.

Comment: Do you have `CompizConfig Settings Manager` installed on your system? If so, have you tweaked any of the settings?

Comment: @heynnema not installed currently. I don't remember using it on this install but I have on previous ones. I don't think that works anymore with 19.10 anyways though

Comment: It looks similar to this issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185142/after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-19-10-i-see-issues-when-resizing-windows-or-dragging-w?rq=1
So im guessing it's somehow related to an extension ive installed but doing the same thing that that person did didn't work.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
```

And then logging out and back in seems like it has fixed it for me at least temporarily.

Certainly seems to be extensions related and the desktop-icons one seems to be the culprit. Similar issue / resolution as [After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10 I see issues when resizing windows or dragging windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185142/after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-19-10-i-see-issues-when-resizing-windows-or-dragging-w?rq=1)